# Is it possible to render two video file on a one surfaceview for blending on Android?

Tags: android, surfaceview, blending

Is it possible to render two video streams on a one `surfaceview` for blending?

I wanna make an application to render two videos for blending to a one same `surfaceview` and then save as a video file.

If that's impossible, is this approach possible that render two videos using two `surfaceview` for blending and save as a one video file?

Please help me.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You'll need to use multiple `SurfaceTexture`s instead, one per video decoder, and render all the textures into one view using Open GL.

See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html for more explanations on how this works; in particular, each `Surface` can only have one producer and one consumer.

Comment: Could I get some examples and GitHub link like related about that?